react cookie - 2 cookies are set with same name and domain, but different path and data
using react-cookie I set a cookie with my access token like the following:
import { Cookies } from "react-cookie";

const cookies = new Cookies();
cookies.set(
    cookieName,
    token,
    {
       domain: ".mydomainhere.com",
       path: "/"
    }
  );

this cookie is set only once when signing in.
everything works fine (just one cookie with the correct info set) until I refresh the page on a not empty path like on www.mydomainhere.com/project/ABC123 (refreshing on www.mydomainhere.com/ works fine). At this point another cookie with the same domain and name shows up and path equal to /project with an out of date token - it's the one before the latest token. The other cookie (path /) has the correct token, but since the browser uses the cookie with the longest path, I get an expired token error.
The cookie removal code is set as:
cookies.remove(cookieName, {
    path: "/",
    domain: ".mydomainhere.com"
  });

I saw several other questions similar to that, but none matched my issue here.
I expected to always have only 1 cookie since I set its path as / and react-cookie docs clearly says to use / as the path if you want your cookie to be accessible on all pages. I tried in multiple paths and they all bring the same issue, only changing the path of the duplicated cookie
